# How to make Zurb emails *un*responsive

Tags: css, zurb-ink

I have a project that uses Zurb ink for many things, but one email in particular is an invoice, whose tables I don't want to shift around when I'm on a smaller screen (I'd rather scroll).

Is there an easy way to disable wrapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the way css works (cascading style sheets) you'll need to override the inline styles and the wrapping with a few !important lines in a media query at the top of your mail in the style tag.

For example:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
 td .example { width: 100% !important };
}
```

Or if you're using Inky only use the attribute `large` on your `<columns>` tag. Consequently, the `small` attribute will copy the value of the `large` attribute.

Comment: It works, but using `!important` is definitely a last resort, it makes things really hard for future changes/development.

Comment: In email development this is the way to go as you have to override your inline styling. There is no other way as far as I know.